# Finding the coefficients in fractional order polynomials with maple

Tags: numerical-methods, math-software, maple

I want to find coefficients in fractional order polynomials with Maple software but I'm having trouble.
For example,
$$
coeff(x+x^{1/2},x,1/2)
$$
 or 
$$
coeff(2x^{3/2},x,3/2)
$$
Please guide me,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is that these are, unsurprisingly, not considered to be polynomials.  The simplest method to achieve your aim is to do

```
coeff(MultiSeries:-series(subs(x=u^2,x+x^(1/2)),u),u,1);
```

and

```
coeff(MultiSeries:-series(subs(x=u^2,2*x^(3/2)),u),u,3);
```

where the pattern should be clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dear Jacques Carette.